# How to use a docker container name instead of IP for DB connection with knex

Tags: docker, knex.js

I have a postgresql DB in a docker container, and a backend API in another docker container (nodeJS).  Both of these containers are launched using docker-compose, therefore are using the bridge network.

If I use a standard http post request in the node backend API I can connect to the DB using the DB's docker container's name (as expected) as follows (snippet showing settings only):

```
const UN = 'postgres';
const PW = '<PW>';
const host = 'myContainerName:5432';
const database = '<DB>';

const expireDuration = 120;

//DB Connection object (client)
var conString = "postgres://" + UN + ":" + PW + "@" + host + "/" + database;
...
```

This works, as the container name (3 lines down) is interpreted by some sort of NAT association within Docker (I don't understand the inner workings of Docker very well).  But I understand using the container name is necessary as IP addresses may change for containers.

My wish now however is to connect to the postgresql DB using Knex within the backend API instead, as I wish to start using DB migrations, and Knex is my tool of choice for this.

However, Knex only allows me to connect using the docker container's IP address, not its container name, for example (this is the Knex setup):

```
development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host : 'myContainerName:5432',
      //host : '172.20.0.3:5432',
      user : 'postgres',
      password : '<PW>',
      database : '<DB>'
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
}
```

If I switch the comment for the hostname around to be the container name it fails to connect.

Does anybody know if I'm doing something horribly wrong by expecting this to work?  Is there a way of using the container name within Knex?

Comment: I am not sure what `Knex` is but it depends whether your knex is running in another container or on the host. So tell us and we will possibly give you a solution. Also are you using docker-compose to set up your containers or you launch them each manually?

Comment: Hi, Knex is a library imported into the backend API container.  So the docker container setup is exactly the same with and without Knex, its just that by going through Knex as a library I can no longer specify the container name for the connection as I could in the 'vanilla' node Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to connect from `Knex` from your host to db container you will have to expose ports from your db container. This is done by using `-p` option :

```
docker container run -p 5432:5432 dbImageName
```

And you will be able to connect to your db from knex using `localhost:5432` as host.

2. If you are using docker-compose and you want to run knex in another container just place service definition in `docker-compose`. It will create default network and connect all containers to it. And then containers will be accessible from other containers on this NETWORK by their name because of DNS server created underneath.
3. If you are not using docker compose. You can create network yourself :

```
docker network create my_net
```

The driver defaults to `bridge`. Then when running your containers you have to pass `--network` option :

```
docker container run --network=my_net imageName
```

Ofcourse you can still expose ports for your host if you want.

4. Also please try to separate host and port in your config :

```
connection: {
      host : 'myContainerName',
      port : 5432
...
```

5. You can also try to connect with `connection` as string :

```
var pg = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: 'postgres://postgres:pass@myContainerName:5432/db'
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated my question because I realise that I haven't been explicit enough.  I am using docker compose at present, knex is a library in the backend API (nodeJS) container.  So the container config with and without knex is the same, but when I use the container name within the Knex setup it doesn't work (whereas it does without using Knex, so the network is fine), so perhaps passing the connection string might be the way, I'll try that (your point 5), and yes I'll separate the port from the IP, good spot thank you!

Comment: It was point 4 that solved the problem, separating my port from my address!  Well spotted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Docker DNS resolution with container names only works from within containers but you could publish the port to the hosts IP/localhost and connect to that. 
This would look something like this:

```
docker run -p 192.168.2.1:1234:1234
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I'm using docker-compose so the containers should be able to recognise each other's IP by way of the container name (I've added this fact to my question).